# Python: os.listdir alternative/certain extensions

Tags: python, operating-system

Is it possible to see files with certain extensions with the os.listdir command? I want it to work so it may show only files or folders with .f at the end. I checked the documentation, and found nothing, so don't ask.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob) is good at this:

```
import glob
for f in glob.glob("*.f"):
    print(f)
```

Comment: +1 wow, that helped a lot! But cant we just do print(glob.glob("*.py")) ?

Comment: You can do that, glob.glob returns a list, do what you want with it.

Answer (score 21):

Don't ask what?

```
[s for s in os.listdir() if s.endswith('.f')]
```

If you want to check a list of extensions, you could make the obvious generalization,

```
[s for s in os.listdir() if s.endswith('.f') or s.endswith('.c') or s.endswith('.z')]
```

or this other way is a little shorter to write:

```
[s for s in os.listdir() if s.rpartition('.')[2] in ('f','c','z')]
```

Comment: There are a lot of things that are explicit function calls in other languages that are replaced by built-in operations in Python.  It's tricky keeping track sometimes.  For example, the various adapter templates in C++ standard library are simply `lambda` in Python.  It's one of my favorite things about Python.

Comment: "Don't ask" means "don't ask me, 'did you check the documentation, what did it say?'"

Comment: @Ned: I kind of figured that, it was a half-rhetorical question.

Comment: `[s in os.listdir() if s.endswith('.f')]` results in a syntax error here using Python 2.7. `[s for s in os.listdir('.') if s.endswith('.f')]` works

Comment: Just wondering, what is "s" supposed to be here? I tried the code for myself and it works but I find it difficult to understand when seemingly arbitrary variable names are used.

Comment: @q-compute It's just a variable which gets set to the name of each file in the directory in turn. The name is arbitrary so you can write it out for yourself with a different variable name if that makes it easier for you to understand.

Answer (score 2):

There is another possibility not mentioned so far:

```
import fnmatch
import os

for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.f'):
        print file
```

Actually this is how the `glob` module is implemented, so in this case `glob` is simpler and better, but the `fnmatch` module can be handy in other situations, e.g. when doing a tree traversal using `os.walk`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from os import listdir

extension = '.wantedExtension'

mypath = r'my\path'

filesWithExtension = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if f[(len(f) - len(extension)):len(f)].find(extension)>=0 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[s for s in os.listdir() if os.path.splitext(s) == 'f']
```

Comment: This should be `os.path.splitext(s)[1] == '.f'`.