# What is the alternative to Python os.listdir()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

When I execute the below command in python, the console gives an error
Note: I am working **windows 10 environment**

```
>>> os.listdir()

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>, line 1, in <module>

TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: os.listdir alternative/certain extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122514/python-os-listdir-alternative-certain-extensions)

Answer (score 7):

You need to use listdir() with a path like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

# Open a file
path = "/var/www/html/"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
  print(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to use

```
os.listdir(os.getcwd())
```

This lists the current working directory (`os.getcwd()` returns the path)

Comment: this might be answer but I want directories also to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

This **TypeError: listdir() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)** 
generally doesn't occur when you run the same command in Jupyter Notebook as path variables are already settled up when you launch a notebook. But you are running .py scripts you can sort it below way.

```
import os             #importing library 
path=os.getcwd()      #will return path of current working directory in string form
a=os.listdir(path)    #will give list of items in directory at <path> location same as bash command "ls" on a directory
```

Or you can manually give path as,

```
import os
path='/home/directory1/sub_directory'
a=os.listdir(path)
```

You can **print a** to checkout

```
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `os.listdir()`, `os.walk()` is a way better alternative -

```
path = 'set/to/your/path'
filetups = [(r,f) for r,d,f in os.walk(path)]
print([i+'/'+k for i,j in filetups for k in j])
```

This should give you a complete list of the file paths under the path you want to explore.