# Python in Sublime Text 3: oslist dir; list specific extensions only

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to make a small tweak to [this Sublime Text 3 plugin](https://github.com/dansheffler/MyWiki) making this is my first foray into Python.

The plugin provides a list of Markdown files when the command `[[` is entered in the keyboard. The thing is that other files show up on the list that I do not want to appear!

From what I've gathered, the bulk of the command demands on `os.listdir(directory)`. I'm aware that trying to list only specific extensions with os.listdir has been inquired of previously such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3122514/python-os-listdir-alternative-certain-extensions) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python), but I just don't understand how to go about implementing those answers into the code that I have. Like others have sought, I'm trying to figure out how to show **only** `.md` files using os.listdir, but the exception is that I'm looking to do so in the scope of this plugin.

The code for the plugin in it's entirety is available [here](https://github.com/dansheffler/MyWiki/blob/master/MyWiki.py).

Below is an excerpt that includes what I would imagine is the more relevant details of my dilemma.

```
class GetWikiLinkCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def on_done(self, selection):
        if selection == -1:
            self.view.run_command(
                "insert_wiki_link", {"args":
                {'text': '[['}})
            return
        self.view.run_command(
            "insert_wiki_link", {"args":
            {'text': '[['+self.modified_files[selection]+']]'}})

    def run(self, edit):
        settings = sublime.load_settings('MyWiki.sublime-settings')
        directory = settings.get('wiki_directory')
        directory = os.path.expanduser(directory)
        extension = settings.get('wiki_extension')

        self.outputText = '[['
        self.files = os.listdir(directory) 
        self.modified_files = [item.replace(extension,"") for item in self.files]
        self.view.window().show_quick_panel(self.modified_files, self.on_done)
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: After a brief look at "the code for the plugin in it's entirety" I'd say you also need to `import os.path`. Note that `import os` does not automatically also import `os.path`. You are importing `re` and `subprocess` but not using those modules in the code. I'd say what you need is: `import sublime, sublime_plugin, os, os.path`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the simplest fix is to change this line:

```py
self.files = os.listdir(directory)
```

to

```py
self.files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith('.md')]
```

Alternatively, if you add `glob` and `os.path` to the import statement, you could do:

```py
self.files = [os.path.basename(p) for p in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.md'))]
```

which might be more performant, if glob is able to filter files faster - not sure about that.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!! It looks like I was on the right track, but I didn't realize the importance that the square brackets played in implementing the function correctly (if function is not the correct term, excuse me). I appreciate your help and I would like you to know that I visited your web page this past June and ended up adding it to my bookmarks. Fancy seeing you here.

Comment: That's quite a coincidence! It's always nice to hear someone found my site interesting :) Glad I was able to help. The brackets with a 'for' inside them specify a 'list comprehension', you can read more about that here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions